# MySQL Error in Nested Query

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have the following code in PHP:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT (
        SELECT `forum_posts.id`,`forum_posts.author`,`forum_posts.author_id`, `forum_boards.date`, MIN(`forum_posts.date`) FROM `forum_posts`
        WHERE `parent` IN
            (SELECT `id` FROM `forum_boards` WHERE `parent`="'.Oflow(intval((isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '0'))).'")
        INNER JOIN `forum_boards`
        ON `forum_boards.id`=`forum_posts.id`
        ORDER BY `update_date` DESC
        LIMIT 1
        GROUP BY `parent`;
    ) ORDER BY `order_large`,`order`;
) UNION (
    SELECT `name`,`id`,`info`,`parent_name` FROM `forum_boards` WHERE `parent`="'.Oflow(intval((isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '0'))).'" ORDER BY `order_large`,`order
)
```

This is a script to get a list of boards and posts in a forum system. What it's supposed to do is get data from a table "boards" and "posts". It then tries to find the most recent post in the sub-board of the board currently being viewed. Then, it tries to join the "parent" and board "id" togeather, in order that the columns can be matched and the posts be sorted accordingly. Finally, a UNION is performed to combine the newly found and ordered posts with the actual forum data.

The error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `forum_boards` ON `forum_boards.id`=`forum_posts.id` ORDER BY' at line 7

The problem is, it don't work! I've double checked every column and table name, and they all exist. This is a very "alpha" code, so if you have any efficiency tips that's be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can't INNER JOIN in the WHERE clause which is what your query is trying to do

```
SELECT (
    SELECT (
        SELECT `forum_posts.id`,`forum_posts.author`,`forum_posts.author_id`, `forum_boards.date`, MIN(`forum_posts.date`) FROM `forum_posts`
        WHERE `parent` IN
            (SELECT `id` FROM `forum_boards` WHERE `parent`="'.Oflow(intval((isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '0'))).'")
        INNER JOIN `forum_boards` ## This is effectively JOINing within a WHERE clause
        ON `forum_boards.id`=`forum_posts.id`
        ORDER BY `update_date` DESC
        LIMIT 1
        GROUP BY `parent`;
    ) ORDER BY `order_large`,`order`;
) UNION (
    SELECT `name`,`id`,`info`,`parent_name` FROM `forum_boards` WHERE `parent`="'.Oflow(intval((isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '0'))).'" ORDER BY `order_large`,`order
)
```

You might need to rethink your query a little bit.

Comment: So do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: @ConnorPeet I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to achieve. Maybe post some sample data and some sample output to clarify it.